# how to remove or prevent duplicate values table .map jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show all the values in column 2 of my table in an alert. This works perfectly with the code below, however it also include duplicate values. My question is: how do i prevent or remove duplicate values within this code?

```
let test = $('#example_table').find('td:nth-child(2)').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().match(/\d+\|\d+/).toString();
 }).get().join();
 alert(test);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It's always better to push only unique data to a table, rather than removing duplicates after rendering.

Comment: @Shiladitya thanks for your comment, however the table is dynamic with user input so it's not possible to push unique data into the table

Comment: If it is user input, then you might be save the user input somewhere right? Just get the unique value every rendering.

Comment: Put those array values into  a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the Set will only contain unique values

Answer (score 0):

only missing part in your code is `g` which is needed to find all references.

Here you go.....

```
let test = $('#example_table').find('td:nth-child(2)').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().match(/\d+\|\d+/g).toString();
 }).get().join();
 alert(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your responses, in particular @charlietfl & @SAURABH

I've come up with the following solution which works perfectly to not have duplicates in the log.

```
let test1 = $('#example_table').find('td:nth-child(2)').map(function () {
        return $(this).text().match(/\d+\|\d+/g).toString();
    }).get();
let test2 = [...new Set(test1)];
    console.log(test2);
```